# PhpStorm: Is there a way to show method name in the show usages popup?

Tags: phpstorm

I would like to see, besides the line number, the method name in the "Show usages" popup as in the image below:

[image: PhpStorm's show usages popup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the toolbar, there's the `File Structure` button (`[m]`) that does exactly that.

[image]